# Confirm of using GPU in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am to confirm that I am using GPU with tensorflow but I am kinda confused. So, I am using the following code to check if GPU is used:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

which outputs the following:

[image]

From my understanding it seems from the output that GPU is used for calculations. But when I monitor it with:

```
~$sudo nvidia-smi --loop=1
```

I have the following output, which constantly gives the following result:

[image]

From my undestanding in the last pic it doesnt use GPU. Is it something that I missunderstound? Any tip?

**Edit** (after Yaroslav Bulatov comment, which helped a lot)

I can confirm now that I am using GPU. For a `matmul(A,B)` I got the following results from the ctf file:

[image]

However there are some functions from tensorflow that seems they are using CPU. For example `tf.nn.top_k`:
[image]

Interesting..

Comment: The GPU is in P0 power state which means it is active, not idling. However just having the context created may cause this, I think.

Comment: you should look at timeline to see which ops are getting run by GPU and how long it takes -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for ur comment.

Comment: Not every Tensorflow operator has a GPU implementation. Most do, but some do not. So it is not surprising to see a handful of operators running on the CPU.